# parse_url PHP_URL_QUERY get a l value

Tags: php

with the URL

domain.com/index.php?option=component&ctrl=product&task=show&cid=5076

```
$parse = parse_url( $full_url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
echo $parse['ctrl']; // I get nothing
```

How can I get my values from keys (option, ctrl, task, and cid)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) along with [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php),

```
$full_url = "domain.com/index.php?option=component&ctrl=product&task=show&cid=5076";
parse_str(parse_url($full_url,PHP_URL_QUERY), $arr); // parse query string
print_r($arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/tEFH5)

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [option] => component
    [ctrl] => product
    [task] => show
    [cid] => 5076
)
```

Comment: it works , thank you